# Predicting the nature of filters

Tags: filter

I heard that one can predict the nature (low pass, high pass...) of an active/passive filter just by looking at the filter response in high and low frequencies. How exactly can that be done?

Comment: This could be a really important question if it asked how the transient response of a filter could be estimated by examining the frequency response or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your filter is simple and you just want to classify it as low pass or high pass, you only need to find two frequencies at which the response differs.  As the name says, "low pass" passes low frequencies and by implication attenuates high frequencies.  A "high pass" does the opposite.  If the filter shows a higher response from the low frequency than the high, then it is low pass.  A high pass filter will show a higher response for the higher frequency.

Generally the "filter response" *is* it's gain as a function of frequency.  Therefore looking at its response at high and low frequencies is measuring it directly, not somehow inferring it.

There are clever ways to infer the frequency response of a filter from its response to various single events in the time domain, like a step or a blip.  Those do require some cleverness and use of Fourier's math, but that is not what you asked about.

Answer (score 2):

When you are first learning about filters it can be helpful to determine the response of a filter at d.c. (0Hz) and at infinite frequency. This is usually easy to do by inspection and can improve your intuition about filters. At d.c. replace capacitors with an open circuit and inductors with a short circuit. At infinite frequency replace capacitors with a short circuit and inductors with an open circuit.

You will often find that at 0Hz the output is identical to the input but at infinite frequency the output must be zero, or vice versa. In these two cases (again for simple filters) you might assume that the filter is a low-pass or a high-pass filter, respectively. If the response (ratio of output voltage to input) looks like zero in both cases then you might suspect a band-pass filter, where if the output was essentially the same as the input in both cases you might suspect a band-reject filter.

This is an enormously simplified analysis and is intended only to help you develop an understanding of very simple filter structures. I suggest it because it generally doesn't require much math and is conceptually simple.

Answer (score 1):

Well the frequency response tells you what will happen to each frequency when you put it through your system. If it will have gain or attenuation.

If you see that for the higher frequencies the magnitude or the length of the lines are a lot smaller than the low frequencies then you can see that it is a low pass filter. As low frequencies are relatively unaffected whereas the higher frequencies are all attenuated indicating that only low frequencies can pass through your system.

If it was the other way around then it would be a high pass filter.

If you saw a hump , where frequencies either side had low magnitude then its a band pass.

Hope that helps, I would draw some pictures to help explain by I'm not at the computer right now. I'll do them later if you still need them :)